# "Import Textfile as Layer" generates only 1 feature

Tags: qgis, csv, import, text

I have a text file containing adresses with coordinates wich looks like this:

```
[...]
N;DEBYv00018000101;A;09;4;75;120;0001;00000;9;;4496255,330;5571332,790;Brunnenstraße;95182;Döhlau;, Kr Hof, Saale;Döhlau;;
N;DEBYv00018000106;A;09;4;75;120;0001;00000;10;;4496153,010;5571475,360;Dahlienweg;95182;Döhlau;, Kr Hof, Saale;Döhlau;;
N;DEBYv00018000111;A;09;4;75;120;0001;00000;11;;4496086,420;5571470,390;Dahlienweg;95182;Döhlau;, Kr Hof, Saale;Döhlau;;
N;DEBYv00018000117;A;09;4;75;120;0001;00000;13;;4496066,170;5571481,620;Dahlienweg;95182;Döhlau;, Kr Hof, Saale;Döhlau;;
[...]
```

No field names are given in a first line and fields are separated by `;`. The file has 1504 lines and what I get when opening this file is not the expected 1504 features with 19 attributes each but only one feature with 28575 attributes as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

The settings seem correct to me, so what am I probably missing?

Comment: Is it normal that you checked both `tabulator` and `semikolon` as field separators?

Comment: Works here when pasting the 4 example rows into a new text file. May be file-specific / line ending issue ... usually only affects Macs

Comment: thx for this hint! It's Win7, and as I just realised it must be a line ending issue. Notepad++ opens the file with correct linebreaks, but Windows editor displays it as a single line. In NPP status line I see its a Macintosh file an can right click > convert it to Win/DOS. This fixes my problem. I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the file I tried to open is a **Macintosh** file. This can be converted to Windows/DOS linebreaks using Notepadd++. In the status line it can be seen which kind of file is handled. Right click opens a small context menu which allows to convert Macintosh > Windows/DOS > UNIX:

[image]